# Can a transaction have a single 0-value OP_RETURN as its only output?

Tags: transactions, op-return, dust

My goal is to create a transaction that spends dust outputs to a miner. Since the goal is to reduce the UTXO set by consuming low value outputs, I do not want to create any new UTXO by actually sending Bitcoin to an address.

Is it valid to make a transaction with several inputs and only one single, zero value ***prunable*** OP RETURN output?

Comment: there are ~50 million UTXO. your efforts are teardrop in ocean

Comment: It's a technical question not a charity proposal. But consider all those useless UTXOs produced by Counterparty. A large scale clean up could be effective

Comment: Services like http://www.cryptograffiti.info/ encode arbitrary data in unspent outputs every single day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Such transactions are valid and standard.